# User Control in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, controls

I have a hyperlink as a user control. When I click it, I need to open a new popup window.
My code is like this:

CType(hypowner.FindControl("txtEmp"), HyperLink).NavigateUrl = "EmployeeDetails.aspx?empno=" + myPlant.OwnerID

Here, "hypowner" is the hyperlink on my current page. "txtemp" is the hyperlink from my user control. The same way, I got to do for ten such controls. They take different query strings. 
Could someone help me with this please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`window.open`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:window.open(...)">Text</a>
```

**Edit**

If the `href` is already set, you can use something like this:

```
<a
    href="http://www.google.com/"
    onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, ...);return false;"
>Text</a>
```

Comment: The problem is that I have around 10 hyperlinks like that, which have to open with different query strings. so, I use them in my vb file like so:


CType(hyppm.FindControl("txtEmp"), HyperLink).NavigateUrl = "EmployeeDetails.aspx?empno=" + myPlant.PlantManagerID

Comment: Make changes in your question by writing some code you tried and the exact one you needed